# Java rounding Issue

Tags: java

I have a case, such that, if the float value is 74.126, it is rounded into 74.13 ie. into 2 decimal places. But if the value is 74.125, it should be rounded into 74.12...

Please help me to achieve this kind of rounding methodology

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's standard math to round up when x.5 and round down when < x.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `BigDecimal` instead of `float`, as that's a more natural representation where *decimal* digits make sense.

However, I don't think you actually want the `round` method, as that deals with *precision* instead of *scale*. I think you want `setScale`, as demonstrated here:

```
import java.math.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    roundTo2DP("74.126");
    roundTo2DP("74.125");
  }

  private static void roundTo2DP(String text) {
    BigDecimal before = new BigDecimal(text);
    BigDecimal after = before.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
    System.out.println(after);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are rounding with `Math.round(float a)`? If so the javadocs explain pretty much how rounding works better than I can here.

You may want to look at the `BigDecimal` class as it provides a `round(MathContext mc)` method that allows you to specify different rounding modes such as `HALF_DOWN`.

Edit:
If you just want to set the number of decimal places you can do it with the `setScale` method.

```
float f = 74.125f;
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(f).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
```